Crank arm rubs on front Deralier
I have a Giant Talon MTB.
I find when I select the largest chain ring at the front, the crank arm rubs on the derailleur.
I've managed to dial it out by using the barrel adjuster.
Now when the middle front chain ring is selected, the chain rubs on the derailleur guard when the bottom 3 cogs are selected in the rear.

Could you add photos to your question?

Instead of the barrel adjuster, you should limit the travel of your derailleur with the limit screws. In your case, the "H" limit screw needs to be adjusted to stop the derailleur from moving too far outward. You will need to correct your barrel adjuster setting back to what it was wo allow correct positioning over the middle chainring.
Details on how to correctly align and adjust your front derailleur can be found all over the internet, for example here: Park Tools Front Derailleur Adjustment
